# jquery - on form sumit, "return true" doesn't work

Tags: jquery, return, submit

my form submit doesn't work correctly. The return var is alway false. But the Function "countCart()" in $.get() works fine. So have to be return true or not? What's going wrong??

```
$("#bestellung-dbr").submit(function() {
    success = false;

    if($("#agb").is(':checked') == false) {
        alert("Bitte stimmen Sie unseren AGBs zu");
        success = false;
    } else {
        $.get("fileadmin/default/templates/scripts/emptyCart.ajax.php", function(result) {
            success = true;
            countCart();
        }); 
    }

    return success;
  });
```

Thx. Marcel

Answer (score 1):

The $.get method calls your callback function asynchronously, which means the code will fall through to the return statement before the callback has a chance to set "success" to true - always returning false. You will probably want to restructure your code, so that the submit function always returns false, and then have your callback take the next step - be it refreshing the DOM or navigating pages, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your fast Answer!!

When it always will be false i can't submit the Form!

I don't solved the problem but i found a useful solution.

I do a $.post ("file.php", $("#form").serialize ()) after my $.get () to submit the form.

Nevertheless, i am interested to solve the main problem.